# Athena: select between dates and certain hours

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, date-arithmetic

I have a database that contains a series of events and times.

I want to know how to write a query where:

```
cast(date_parse(date_time, ‘%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s))
```

is between certain dates (ex. 1/1/22 - 1/1/23) AND hours is between (ex. 6am - 3pm)

Not sure on how to incorporate both between dates as well as specific hours of day

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the date part with a half-open interval, then use `extract` to check the hour portion:

```
select *
from mytable
where date_time >= date '2022-01-01'
  and date_time <  date '2023-01-01'
  and extract(hour from date_time) between 6 and 14
```

This filters on the whole 2022 year, every day between 6 am (included) and 3 pm (excluded).

Comment: isn't it 2 pm??

Comment: well actually it ranges from `06:00:00` to `14:59:59`, @nbk

Comment: When I put the query in Athena, it’s saying: ‘>=‘ can not be applied to varchar, date

Comment: @Randomguy `date_time` -> `date_parse(date_time, ‘%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s)`

Comment: @GuruStron

 I am still getting an error "mismatched input 'between'". Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? 
Here is the query: 
select cast(date_parse(date_time, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s) as date) as day, _userid, count(event_list) from my table
 where date_parse(date_time, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s) >= date '2022-01-01' and date_parse (date_time, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s) < date '2023-01-01'

 and extract(hour from (date_time) between 6 and 14

 group by 1,2

 order by 1

Comment: @Randomguy the provided query heavily misses on `'` and `}`.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a fully working example. First of all I highly recommend to use sub-query (or [`WITH` clause](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-clause)) so you don't need to repeat `date_parse`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (_userid, date_time) as (
    values
        (329, '22-05-01 05:56:03'),
        (329, '22-05-01 12:56:22'),
        (329, '22-05-01 12:58:30'),
        (329, '22-05-01 15:59:22'),
        (329, '22-05-01 15:00:05')
)

-- query
select  cast(date_time as date) day,
        _userid,
        count(*)
from (select _userid, 
          date_parse(date_time, '%y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as date_time -- possibly you will need to "play" with the format
    from dataset)
where date_time >= date '2022-01-01'
    and date_time < date '2023-01-01'
    and extract(hour from date_time) between 6 and 14
group by 1, 2;
```

Output:

| day | _userid | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 329 | 2 |